# Star deletion kernel

Tags: algorithm, parameterized, approximation

In Star Deletion problem, i have a graph G and k ∈ N, and the objective is to decide whether there
exists a subset S ⊆ V(G) of size at most k such that G\S does not contain any 3-star as a subgraph.

Is there a O(k)-vertex kernel for the problem?

The insctructor of the question gave me an hint:
I may use a 4-approximation polynomial-time algorithm for 4-Hitting Set as a black box.